# What is the current status on Microsoft ProClarity?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting, analytics, ssas

I don't really know how to compose this question. My complay has been using Microsoft ProClarity for few years and we have a quite a few users using it publising books and doing ad-hoc analysis. With the new Microsoft BI solutions, it seems like they are completely going away from ProClarity and replacing the OLAP analysis with Excel. I understand the with SharePoint and integration with PerformancePoint and reporting services the dashboards and reports would be done in SharePoint but what about the analysis? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to sure if this answers your question, but Excel 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2 use [PowerPivot](http://www.powerpivot.com) for making BI easier (and more powerful) for (end-)users.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a combination of PerformancePoint, [PowerPivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx) and [PowerView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5fwphWxNoE). PowerView is a very simple, powerful Silverlight dashboard that end users can use for analysis. PowerPivot allows reporting functionality in excel, providing a user with the latest data.

We have found that a BI solution developed using these three technologies are sufficient for users to manage and query large, constantly changing datasets across various sources.